# Why the import url must start with "node:"

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I was checking the node official docs and I found that the import url of the node native modules in the examples of es modules starts with `node:`.

I did not use node very much, maybe there were some huge changes happened. So:

1. Can someone share some links that I can get some context about this change?
2. What if we don't add the `node:` before the import url? I tested a bit and it seems everythings works fine.

Thanks a lot.

```js
import { open } from 'node:fs/promises';

let filehandle;
try {
  filehandle = await open('thefile.txt', 'r');
} finally {
  await filehandle?.close();
}
```

I wrote some node packages and use `"type": "module"` in `pacakge.json` and not use `node:` when I import native modules, I did not see any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/modules.html#core-modules):

> Core modules can be identified using the `node:` prefix, in which case it bypasses the `require` cache. For instance, `require('node:http')` will always return the built in HTTP module, even if there is `require.cache` entry by that name.